# Remove portion of string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a String like this in Javascript:

```
string = '@usernameWhats on your mind?'
```

I need to get rid of `'Whats on your mind?'` from the string.

How would I do that?

Comment: What determines what part of the string you want to get rid of?

Comment: What kind of rules do you know about this string? Is it always prefixed by "@username"? Does the portion that comes afterwards always have a capital first letter?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
var new_string = string.replace('Whats on your mind?', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can `split` the string:

```
string.split("@username"); // ["", "What on your mind?"]
```

Then `pop` removes the last element.

```
const newString = string.split("@username").pop();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP. Especially that this question was asked in 2011 with an answer that is still relevant.