# How to remove a complete tag from a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

My input is as follows

```
input = "hello <script>alert("I am stealing your data");</script>"
```

I want to remove the complete script tag from the string and the output should look like

```
output = "hello"
```

Tried following command but its not removing complete tag.

```
input.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ''));
```

It gives result us

```
"hello alert("I am stealing you data");"
```

Comment: @NinaScholz what is missing? It's a simple straight forward question

Comment: didn't dv. But if the non "hello" part is constant than you could use the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529070/remove-portion-of-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @Dixel given that it's a `script` tag, I wouldn't assume it's constant. This appears to be aimed at sanitising arbitrary data.

Comment: Its not constant. Its the input we get from user. Kind of fixing XSS attack

Comment: Hmm ... If you're getting this string from your server, the attack has already took a place.

Comment: @Teemu Just testing with that input :D

Answer (score 5):

You should [not use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839) regular expressions for this. Instead use the DOM parser capabilities:

```js
var input = 'hello <script\>alert("I am stealing your data");</script\>';

var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = input; // This will not execute scripts
// Remove all script tags within this span element:
Array.from(span.querySelectorAll("script"), script => script.remove()); 
// Get the remaining HTML out of it
var scriptless = span.innerHTML;

console.log(scriptless);
```

Just note that it is a very bad idea to let the user pass arbitrary HTML to your application. Sanitising involves [a lot more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) than just removing script tags.

Comment: *"Sanitising involves a lot more than just removing script tags."* That depends how you want to sanitize your string. A simple two liner would sanitize an html string just fine. `var replacements = { "&": "&amp;", "<": "&lt;", ">": "&gt;", '"': "&quot;", "'": "&apos;" }; str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, match => replacements[match]);`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a regular expression, because those can be easy to trick and are not fit for parsing HTML content, especially not untrusted HTML content.

Instead, you can use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to create a new document and use the DOM API to find and remove all script tags, then return the rest of the content:

```js
function sanitise(input) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(input, "text/html");
  
  //find all script tags
  const scripts = doc.getElementsByTagName('script');

  for (const script of scripts)
    script.remove(); //remove from the DOM
  
  return doc.body.textContent.trim();
}

//using the + because otherwise Stack Snippets breaks
console.log(sanitise("hello <script>alert('I am stealing your data');</scr"+"ipt>"))
```